# Rubymine Remote Ruby Interpreter over SSH not working

Tags: ruby, linux, ssh, rubymine

I have a Windows 8.1 host, with a Ubuntu 12.10LTS server that is run using VirtualBox.

I have 2 network connection set up, first in NAT the second is a "Host-Only-Adapter" which allows me to have a constant connection to the VM without changing IP addresses etc...

On my host machine I have RubyMine 6.3.3. What I want to do is develop on the Windows Machine (the VM is only Ubunut Server, so no desktop)

I keep all the files from GIT on the VM, and have a Mapped Network Drive to edit these in RubyMine.

I am trying to connect to the Ruby Interpreter remotely so I can take advantage of all the features of Rubymine. Under Project Settings > Ruby SDK and Gems > New Remote - I add in all the server details, and the "Test Connection" works fine.

Then I put the path to the Ruby Binaries. But it just sits there saying "connecting" for ever it does not do anything at all.

I have tried System Ruby, RVM and Rbenv and they all do the same. Just hang there for ages and do nothing.

I think what I am trying to do should be possible. It would also be good to handle GIT this way but I can easily use Git from CLI through an SSH connection.

I have emailed JetBrains, but no response yet, if they come back  I will post solution.

I am also very open to new ideas of how to achieve what I want in different ways.

Comment: What are the "server details" that you are entering in "new remote"?

Comment: 192.168.56.101 port 22 / username / password

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this, but I think the fix is a bug that I will report to RubyMine

I added a Deployment Server, with exactly the same settings as the SSH Remote Interpreter.

Once you have done this, you now get an option "Fill from deployment server settings"

Once selected the fields are auto populated, and bingo it connects.

Not sure why this is happening, but this did FIX it, will update if I hear anything from JetBrains

Comment: Had the same bug on Win 10 with RubyMine 7.1.4 - your solution worked for me.